# Adding this formula to a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know why is not working the following code, it gives me an error.

```
Sub addformula()
For i = 10 To 99
    For j = 10 To 99
    Sheet8.Cells(93 + i - 10, 20 + j - 10).Formula = "=IF(OR(AND(J" & i & " = 1; K" & j &  " = 1);AND(J" & j & " = 1; K" & i & " = 1));1;0)"
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add the error you have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use commas `,` instead semicolons `;` (even if you have commas as standart separator):

```
Sub addformula()
    For i = 10 To 99
       For j = 10 To 99
          Sheet8.Cells(93 + i - 10, 20 + j - 10).Formula = "=IF(OR(AND(J" & i & " = 1, K" & j &  " = 1),AND(J" & j & " = 1, K" & i & " = 1)),1,0)"
       Next
    Next
End Sub
```